How long does the local memory of a kernel function in CUDA exist?
#include <stdio.h>

void __global__ test(int N){
    int a;
    a=N+thredIdx.x;
    printf("%d %d %d %p\n",blockIdx.x,threadIdx.x,a,&a);
}

int main(){
    int i,N=10;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        test<<<2,33>>>(i);
        //printf("hhhh\n");
    }
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    return 0;
}

I have a code here, and here is its outputs:
1 32 32 0000029942FFFCD0
0 32 32 0000029942FFFCD0
1 0 0 0000029942FFFCD0
1 1 1 0000029942FFFCD0
1 2 2 0000029942FFFCD0
1 3 3 0000029942FFFCD0
1 4 4 0000029942FFFCD0
1 5 5 0000029942FFFCD0
1 6 6 0000029942FFFCD0
1 7 7 0000029942FFFCD0
1 8 8 0000029942FFFCD0
1 9 9 0000029942FFFCD0
1 10 10 0000029942FFFCD0
1 11 11 0000029942FFFCD0
1 12 12 0000029942FFFCD0
1 13 13 0000029942FFFCD0
1 14 14 0000029942FFFCD0
1 15 15 0000029942FFFCD0
1 16 16 0000029942FFFCD0
1 17 17 0000029942FFFCD0
1 18 18 0000029942FFFCD0
1 19 19 0000029942FFFCD0
1 20 20 0000029942FFFCD0
1 21 21 0000029942FFFCD0
1 22 22 0000029942FFFCD0
1 23 23 0000029942FFFCD0
1 24 24 0000029942FFFCD0
1 25 25 0000029942FFFCD0
1 26 26 0000029942FFFCD0
1 27 27 0000029942FFFCD0
1 28 28 0000029942FFFCD0
1 29 29 0000029942FFFCD0
1 30 30 0000029942FFFCD0
1 31 31 0000029942FFFCD0
0 0 0 0000029942FFFCD0
0 1 1 0000029942FFFCD0
0 2 2 0000029942FFFCD0
0 3 3 0000029942FFFCD0
0 4 4 0000029942FFFCD0
0 5 5 0000029942FFFCD0
0 6 6 0000029942FFFCD0
0 7 7 0000029942FFFCD0
0 8 8 0000029942FFFCD0
0 9 9 0000029942FFFCD0
0 10 10 0000029942FFFCD0
0 11 11 0000029942FFFCD0
0 12 12 0000029942FFFCD0
0 13 13 0000029942FFFCD0
0 14 14 0000029942FFFCD0
0 15 15 0000029942FFFCD0
0 16 16 0000029942FFFCD0
0 17 17 0000029942FFFCD0
0 18 18 0000029942FFFCD0
0 19 19 0000029942FFFCD0
0 20 20 0000029942FFFCD0
0 21 21 0000029942FFFCD0
0 22 22 0000029942FFFCD0
0 23 23 0000029942FFFCD0
0 24 24 0000029942FFFCD0
0 25 25 0000029942FFFCD0
0 26 26 0000029942FFFCD0
0 27 27 0000029942FFFCD0
0 28 28 0000029942FFFCD0
0 29 29 0000029942FFFCD0
0 30 30 0000029942FFFCD0
0 31 31 0000029942FFFCD0
1 32 33 0000029942FFFCD0
0 32 33 0000029942FFFCD0
1 0 1 0000029942FFFCD0
1 1 2 0000029942FFFCD0
1 2 3 0000029942FFFCD0
1 3 4 0000029942FFFCD0
1 4 5 0000029942FFFCD0
1 5 6 0000029942FFFCD0
1 6 7 0000029942FFFCD0
1 7 8 0000029942FFFCD0
1 8 9 0000029942FFFCD0
1 9 10 0000029942FFFCD0
1 10 11 0000029942FFFCD0
1 11 12 0000029942FFFCD0
1 12 13 0000029942FFFCD0
1 13 14 0000029942FFFCD0
1 14 15 0000029942FFFCD0
1 15 16 0000029942FFFCD0
1 16 17 0000029942FFFCD0
1 17 18 0000029942FFFCD0
1 18 19 0000029942FFFCD0
1 19 20 0000029942FFFCD0
1 20 21 0000029942FFFCD0
1 21 22 0000029942FFFCD0
1 22 23 0000029942FFFCD0
1 23 24 0000029942FFFCD0
1 24 25 0000029942FFFCD0
1 25 26 0000029942FFFCD0
1 26 27 0000029942FFFCD0
1 27 28 0000029942FFFCD0
1 28 29 0000029942FFFCD0
1 29 30 0000029942FFFCD0
1 30 31 0000029942FFFCD0
1 31 32 0000029942FFFCD0
0 0 1 0000029942FFFCD0
0 1 2 0000029942FFFCD0
0 2 3 0000029942FFFCD0
0 3 4 0000029942FFFCD0
0 4 5 0000029942FFFCD0
0 5 6 0000029942FFFCD0
0 6 7 0000029942FFFCD0
0 7 8 0000029942FFFCD0
0 8 9 0000029942FFFCD0
0 9 10 0000029942FFFCD0
0 10 11 0000029942FFFCD0
0 11 12 0000029942FFFCD0
0 12 13 0000029942FFFCD0
0 13 14 0000029942FFFCD0
0 14 15 0000029942FFFCD0
0 15 16 0000029942FFFCD0
0 16 17 0000029942FFFCD0
0 17 18 0000029942FFFCD0
0 18 19 0000029942FFFCD0
0 19 20 0000029942FFFCD0
0 20 21 0000029942FFFCD0
0 21 22 0000029942FFFCD0
0 22 23 0000029942FFFCD0
0 23 24 0000029942FFFCD0
0 24 25 0000029942FFFCD0
0 25 26 0000029942FFFCD0
0 26 27 0000029942FFFCD0
0 27 28 0000029942FFFCD0
0 28 29 0000029942FFFCD0
0 29 30 0000029942FFFCD0
0 30 31 0000029942FFFCD0
0 31 32 0000029942FFFCD0

It seems that the address of the variable "a" is always the same. Why?
I thought that the local memery(or the register memory) of a kernel was released after its call was over in every single loop. But it seems not?
to get a further understanding about memory management of Cuda

You should not make any assumption on it. It can be recycled from one kernel call to another. Since multiple kernels might run in parallel, it might not be always the case. Keeping the same addresses is a good thing performance-wise since the cache-lines are probably still in the GPU cache so there is no need to fetch it from the VRAM.

There is no such thing as "register memory" in CUDA. Memory-mapped registers were a thing in the early days of computing; not today. Local memory is more like a thread stack but with special addressing to ensure access is coalesced if all threads within a warp access the same local variable at the same time.

Note also this line from the PTX ISA: "In implementations that do not support a stack, all local memory variables are stored at fixed addresses, recursive function calls are not supported, and .local variables may be declared at module scope"

Thanks for your comment. I am still confused: in a single call of the kernel test<<<1,2>>, two threads are generated, I thought every thread has a duplicate of "a", so they can change its value separately, So every thread should output the address of its own duplicate?

First things first: If you respond to someone, write @Homer512 (or similar) so that we get notified of your response. Only the person writing the question/answer gets an automatic notification. For the confusion: Local memory is thread-private. CUDA is under no obligation to make the pointers unique. In fact, when doing a local memory access, the hardware factors in a scaling factor and thread-specific offset. See also here

First, note that what you see is virtual memory, not physical one. Moreover, your kernel have 1 block and 2 threads. In this case, N is a constant for all threads and so a too. Thus, CUDA might generate a code storing a as a unique shared integer here. That being said, I think it is just that the address you see is local to a thread, so it does not consider the offset of a thread (in practice, it is certainly the case for physical memory which is directly managed by the hardware itself). IDK if this is documented but you are not supposed to do any assumption on this anyway.

I think this is more efficient internally to do that. It is easier for the hardware to check if accesses are coalesced by just checking if all values are the same. If they are not, then this is either a broadcast or a gather/scatter operation. This also avoid adding the offset in the assembly code so to then subtract it later. This means a better efficiency of memory accesses and so possibly a lower energy consumption. In the end, virtual memory is just interleaved physical memory. CPUs does that too for DRAM internally (here again for sake of efficiency).

Oh and btw, generally, a variable cannot be stored in a register any-more if you request its address because registers have no addresses (since there is no "register memory" as pointed out by Homer512). Measurements impact the generated code (like states in quantum mechanics). If you want to see what happen under the hood, it might be better to check the PTX and SASS generated codes.

I am curious of what could happen with multiple blocks (I guess addresses will be different since blocks are not much synchronized so using the same address would make the hardware implementation probably more complicated, especially since multiple blocks can run on multiple SM). I might also be interesting to check what happens with large blocks (i.e. more threads than the size of a warp).

@Jérôme Richard
I edited my question and changed the code according to your kind and instructive comments. Now in the code duplicates of "a" are supposed to be necessary because in every thread the value of "a" is different. and the the call of "test" is changed from<<<1,2>>> to <<<2,33>>>. the result is that the adresses are still all the same

@Jérôme Richard
do I understand you correctly: the outputed address is the relative address within a single thread, and the real address of the duplicate of "a" in a thread should be the sum of the outputed address and a specific offset, which is determined and managed by CUDA and different for every thread?

It's clear that the address is the same for every thread since the "stack pointer" is simply retrieved from constant memory, as discussed in the answer I linked earlier. Mapping to physical (or virtual, global) addresses is likely handled through some form of segmented memory, like x86's use of the FS and GS segment selectors for thread-local variables. But that's just a guess, the real mechanism is not documented, AFAIK

@Jérôme Richard And I asked this question because a guy told me that after a call of a kernel (a single call in a single loop), the threads of this kernel are not over, in the next loop, the threads keep the variable and continue running. I think this is not true,  I think after every call of a kernel, the threads of this kernel is over, in the next loop new threads are re-genrated, new local variables are allocated, assuming that old value of "a" can be used in the next loop is not reasonable.

Results are interesting, especially for multiple blocks. I did not expect the same addresses in multiple blocks unless they are serialized. Yes, it is a kind of relative address : from the user PoV each threads has its own (virtual) address space (similar to processes in x86 protected mode indeed). To better understand the mapping you can print the address of two variable a and b and check the gap between for multiple amount of threads.

Note that, in practice, threads certainly does not have independent address spaces because it would be far too expensive (resulting in huge TLBs while being useless in most cases -- at least for warps). I expect this to be done statically by the hardware. It might be dependent of the target architecture so it is not something you can assume always true (like most undocumented things unfortunately)

No, threads are tied to a kernel. Thus, when a kernel is finished, the associated threads does not exist any-more. Your tests is not a good way to show that. In fact, you can see the same thing on some platforms on CPU where memory is recycled between different thread, which does not prove the threads are recycled since the actual threads have different IDs. Maybe using a thread_local object with a constructor/destructor having a printf inside is a good test to (better) prove that.

@Jérôme Richard
Thanks for your kind and patient instructions! Thanks a lot! wish you a good day!

What that "guy" is talking about sounds more like whether you can read data left behind from a previous thread by reading uninitialized local memory or an uninitialized register. So the better question to ask is, "Are local memory and/or registers reset to zero between threads on the same SM running the same kernel?"

@Homer512 Thanks a lot for you comments! I am quite a new beginner in CUDA and stackoverflow, so I may have some inapproriate expressions and communication methods. Thanks for your instructions and kind remindess! wish you a good day

By the way, note that threads are part of the CUDA model. This is something rather high-level (an abstraction layer). At the hardware level, threads does not really exists AFAIK. The hardware performs SIMD operations and the lane IDs can be seen as thread IDs while lane contenant can be seen as thread variables (it is a bit more complicated since Volta AFAIK though). The SASS code is pretty close to CPU SIMD codes.

@Homer512 Yes. I did a test,:in kernel function，”a" is not initialized, and "a+=threadIdx.x", The result supports that local memory and/or registers do reset to zero between threads. Thanks a lot!

@Homer512 I expect memory of multiple kernels not to be guaranteed to be reset in the same process (for sake of performance). However, for multiple processes (using the same GPU), memory must be reset because it would be a serious security hole otherwise. This is similar to CPU threads recycling allocated memory within the same process (without giving it back to the OS). On CPU and all mainstream OS, requested memory from the OS is always reset to zero for security reasons (though it can be manually disabled). This is a good test to do :) .

@JérômeRichard Yes, I would assume the same. The compiler also doesn't assume zero-initialization for local memory and does explicit memsets to zero if you initialize a local array. Maybe I'll throw together a small test to see how local memory is reused exactly. I would assume it correlates with some of the special registers available in PTX.


It seems that the address of the variable "a" is always the same. Why?

This is not because the function-scope variable a has some magical longevity; it is because, generally, when you run the same code under the same (or close enough) conditions, you are likely to get the same addresses selected for the same variables or heap assignments.
This is just like if you run the same CPU-side program twice, you may well get the same addresses assigned to variables, get the same results for new[] or malloc() calls etc.

Note: Jérôme Richard reminds us in the comments that the addresses are virtual rather than physical, so that the reuse of addresses does not mean you get to access values left over from other threads / program invocations at the same physical location.
